# View Local Administrator accounts on a remote computer using Batch

Tags: batch-file, psexec

Is there a way to remotely view local administrator accounts on remote computers within a network or possibly run *NET LOCALGROUP ADMINISTRATORS* and have the result be viewed on the command prompt instead of extracting it in a notepad (via psexec)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid I do not know your network well enough to say for certain, but I'm inclined to go with **yes**.

Comment: I am not understanding your correlation between notepad and psexec.  If you want to see the output of that `NET` command then just use PSEXEC and it will output it to your screen.

Comment: When I use PSEXEC on my terminal. The output of the command will be shown on the remote computer instead of my terminal so I won't be able to check the Local Accounts on the remote computer. 

Thank you guys for taking your time answering :)

Answer (score 0):

Try a Bat file with this.

for /f %%A in (computers.txt) do (echo Identifying group members on "%%A" ...
psexec -s \%%A net localgroup administrators )

Create a txt file with computer names without spaces one name for each line.

Redirect the command to a txt file and creat a log with it.

Ex. batfile > log.txt